# How to get access of Odoo's records on Interactive mode?

Tags: python, console, odoo, odoo-10

I would like to get access to the records on a Interactive way, through python console.

I found this for older version

```
>>> Partner = odoo.env['res.partner']
>>> partner = Partner.browse(1)     # fetch one record, partner ID = 1
>>> partner
Recordset('res.partner', [1])
```

And newer versions it is like

`wt = self.env['model.name']`

But where does 'self' comes from?

Comment: Can you specify the particular versions you have tried? `self` is a reference to an object from one of its methods, so you probably need to change the paradigm of accessing the value

Comment: @peci1 I'm using odoo 10 and python 2.7

Comment: @peci1 when I try to use odoo.env, I get this error
. `'module' object has no attribute 'env'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I never used that framework. Did you try to search for a migration guide?